# Add months to date column in Spark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a scenario where I want to add months to a date column in spark `DataFrame` which has two columns with data type (Date, Int)

e.g.

```
df.show()
```

```
data_date months_to_add
2015-06-23 5
2016-07-20 7
```

I want to add a new column which will have a new date (After adding months to existing date) and output will look like below-

```
data_date month_to_add new_data_date
2015-06-23 5           2015-11-23
2016-07-20 1           2016-8-20
```

I have tried below piece of code, but it does not seems to be working-

```
df = df.withColumn("new_data_date", a
  dd_months(col("data_date"), col("months_to_add")))
```

it gives me error-

```
'Column' object is not callable
```

Please help me if there is any method to achieve this without using SQL query on top of dataframe.

Comment: What is `add_months` ?

Comment: @jeanr: add_months is a predefined spark function to add month (an integer value) to a date

Comment: did you register add_months as a UDF ?

Comment: any other approach will also work, i couldn't find anything related to adding month to a date.

Comment: @Chitral: add_months is predefined function in spark

Comment: See user8371915 answer. That would work. As for the question why it is throwing error for you, add_columns expect a column parameter for the date and an integer value for the months to add. You're giving both columns here that's why you are getting this error.

Comment: I am trying to to the same thing, but getting a `column is not iterable` error.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'd use `expr`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [("2015-06-23", 5), ("2016-07-20", 7)],
    ("data_date", "months_to_add")
).select(to_date("data_date").alias("data_date"), "months_to_add")

df.withColumn("new_data_date", expr("add_months(data_date, months_to_add)")).show()

+----------+-------------+-------------+
| data_date|months_to_add|new_data_date|
+----------+-------------+-------------+
|2015-06-23|            5|   2015-11-23|
|2016-07-20|            7|   2017-02-20|
+----------+-------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Looks neat. However, which add_months does it take? I don't think it takes pyspark.sql.functions.add_months.

Comment: @DeSanta It's a hive function either way.

Comment: @user8371915 Thank you so much..this worked like a charm!

Comment: @philantrovert I tried it in pyspark shell. Without importing add_months, it worked for me. And expr takes a string. I want to know how it worked without even importing.

Comment: @DeSanta It's a hive function. You can execute it using `sqlContext.sql` as well. That's why.

Comment: Got it. Thank you :)

Answer (score -2):

since function add_months expect second argument as integer and you are passing column value you are getting an error.

Try using below statement and check

```
df.withColumn("new_data_date",add_months(col("data_date"), df.first()[1])).show()
```

Hope it helps.

Regards,

Neeraj

Answer (score -2):

Try Below code. It is working for me.

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
l =  [("2015-06-23", 5),("2016-07-20", 7)]
rdd1 = sc.parallelize(l)
row_rdd = rdd1.map(lambda x: Row(x[0], x[1]))
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(row_rdd,['data_date', 'months_to_add'])
df.withColumn("new_data_date",add_months(col("data_date"), df.first()[1])).show()
```

Regards,
Neeraj